# Changing Job during the probation period as a WebDev

Tags: job-offer, quitting

I am a Web Developer in Germany who started a new job at an agency three months ago which I really do like working for. Now someone at a major tech company was offering me a position and it's a really attractive offer. The payment and the benefits I would get are great. Under normal circumstances I would just immediately take the offer but my situation is a bit different.

I only started a job three months ago and they really put some effort into teaching me their business rules and used resources for that. They also sent me to a conference which was a nice thing to do. It would be really a bad move from me if I just left the company. Since I'm in probation I could almost immediately do that but I'm in a real struggle.

Should I tell my supervisor that I will be leaving but I am willing to stay until they find someone else but no longer than the end of my probation period (of which I have three months left)? Because finding competent emlpoyees and teaching them the business rules does really mean effort. Or do I care too much and should I better be just leaving?

What options do I have besides that? I don't want to disappoint my current employer and I want to split in good terms because I really like the current company.

But the job offer at that new company is like winning the lottery and in terms of my career it would be pretty stupid not to take the offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contractually, I would say that there is nothing to prevent you from taking the offer from the other company. But do your own verification to make sure.

Since your current employer is treating you well, I suggest that you set up an appointment with your manager and be upfront about the offer you have received. See how your manager reacts.

If your manager asks you whether you have made your decision, tell him that you want to take off but you have been so well treated here that it's tough to make the decision to leave. Ask the manager what the manager would do if the manager were in your boots.

You owe your current company a quick decision whichever way your decision goes. If you decide to leave, stress how much you liked being at your current company and that you would have stayed but for the offer. Do the best you can to be as cooperative as possible and to leave on good terms. Stress that you still want to stay in touch even as you leave.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! Espsecially I like the part you wrote about asking my manager what he would do in my situation because that puts the course of action to him. I'll wait for other opinions and then accept your answer :) thanks

Comment: Agreed. Remember that probation cuts both ways; they reserve the right to drop you during that period if it's a bad fit, but you have the same right. The important thing is to do so as courteously as possible. Offering to stay on for up to three months, and to help train whoever will be taking over your responsibilities, is also a fine gesture. Depending on how grumpy Management feels you may get barked at a bit about the investment they've made in you, but these things happen and if this is  a career move they should respect that. Reminder: get the offer IN WRITING before doing anything else!